# How to add/update record in a table by stored procedure in SQL Server when added/updated happens in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table as described below

Main table:

```
id, application, type
1, ram, good
2, ramesh, average
3, suresh, good
```

Secondary table

```
application_s, rank
ram, 2
ramesh, 4
suresh,1
```

Now.. the scenario is "ram" application replaced with "Ramarajan" and "Suresh" with "Suresh kumar" in Main table.

How to do the above update in SQL Server using a stored procedure or any?

Comment: So you want to automatically update the secondary table when the  application changes in the primary table ?

Comment: Either create a stored procedure which updates both tables and call that from your app. Or put a trigger on the main table which updates you secondary table.

Comment: I'd say the approach is incorrect at all. Yes, you can have a trigger at the first table, or a stored procedure, which updates both tables keeping them consistent. But a proper approach is to have a table for names (id, name), and then both your tables referring to the name table by a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create a trigger on the main table, that fires as follows :

- when the main table is `UPDATE`d and the `application` is changed, it is changed in the secondary table too
- when a record is `DELETE`d from the main table, the corresponding record(s) that have the same application in the secondary table are deleted
- when a new record is `INSERT`ed into the main table, a new record is also inserted in the secondary table (with other columns empty).

Code :

```
create trigger maintable_trigger
on maintable
after UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE
as
    if exists(select * from inserted) and exists (SELECT * from deleted)     --update
    begin
        update s 
        set s.application_s = i.application
        from secondarytable s
        inner join deleted d on d.application = s.application_s
        cross join inserted i;
    end

    if exists (select * from inserted) and not exists(Select * from deleted) --insert
    begin
        insert into secondarytable select i.application, null from inserted i;
    end

    if exists(select * from deleted) and not exists(Select * from inserted)  --delete 
    begin
        delete from secondarytable
        where exists (
            select 1 from deleted d where d.application = secondarytable.application_s
        )
    end
```

**[See it in action in this DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=98b460d15f481ed81389b152f3df196d)**